# How to set timeout in camunda in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, timeout, camunda

I want to set a timeout for 120 minutes in the session of Camunda.
This is the configuration in my pom.xml :

```
...
...
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.camunda.bpm.springboot</groupId>
            <artifactId>camunda-bpm-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.camunda.bpm.springboot</groupId>
            <artifactId>camunda-bpm-spring-boot-starter-webapp</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.camunda.bpm.springboot</groupId>
            <artifactId>camunda-bpm-spring-boot-starter-rest</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.camunda.bpm</groupId>
            <artifactId>camunda-engine-rest-core</artifactId>
            <version>7.8.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
...
...
```

I tried a lot of tracks, two of which are the most proposed on the forums, one to use if spring boot version is < 1 and the other if spring boot is > 2 :

```
server.connection-timeout=...
server.servlet.session.timeout=...
```

For the version of dependecies :

```
<springboot.version>2.3.0</springboot.version>
<version.camunda>7.8.0</version.camunda>
```

Are there other possibilities to set the timeout session ?

Answer (score 0):

I achieved something similar using spring session, when using spring boot 2.x.x.

My `pom.xml` has these dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-session-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-session-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Using these, Camunda will rely on spring session for session management so you can control session using standard options provided by spring session. However, keep in mind this will use you persistence layer (postgres/h2/etc).

There's a [spring.session.timeout](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/application-properties.html#application-properties.web.spring.session.timeout) available, try setting that one to `120m` in `application.properties` / `application.yaml`.

I have these in my `application.yaml` config file

```
spring:
  session:
    store-type: jdbc
    jdbc.initialize-schema: always
```